# typo3 realurl chash

Tags: php, caching, typo3, realurl

I am trying to setup realurl to work with my extension.

I think I am doing something wrong because I can't get rid of the cHash
parameter. My realurl config is

#### REALURL START

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
    'fileName' => array(),
    'init' => array(
        'enableCHashCache' => true,
             'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
              'adminJumpToBackend' => true,
              'enableUrlDecodeCache' => true,
              'enableUrlEncodeCache' => true,
              'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
    ),
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'redirects' => array(),
        'preVars' => array(),
        'pagePath' => array(
        'type' => 'user',
        'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            'expireDays' => 30,
            'rootpage_id' => '1',
        ),
        'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array(
                'kategori' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_projgallery_pi1[cat]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array(
                            'table' => 'tx_projgallery_categories',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'category',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => '1',
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                'strtolower' => '1',
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'album' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_projgallery_pi1[album]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array(
                            'table' => 'tx_projgallery_gallery',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'navi_title',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => '1',
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                'strtolower' => '1',
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'billede' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_projgallery_pi1[show]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array(
                            'table' => 'tx_projgallery_photos',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'uid',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => '1',
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                'strtolower' => '1',
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                            )
                        ),
                    ),

                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

#### REAL URL END

I have googled it like a maniac but did find any helpful info.
Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: IMO: Cooluri is better. For example when you have some normal links referencing a seo friendly link it doesn't break the application.

Comment: Have you got all parameters covered in your postVarSet? If not (e.g. the `type` parameter) it will append a `cHash`

Comment: I am pretty certain that all param are set in postVarSet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Check your extension configuration. Are all tables and fields created? If not try to create the tables and fields via phpMyAdmin on your own.
- Check if table tx_realurl_chashcache is there, it should not be empty.
- Activate `enableChashUrlDebug` in realurl extension configuration.
- Activate `enableDevLog` in realurl extension configuration
- Install extension devlog

So, check the log and the cache-tables for errors.

Deactivate realurl and check the links. Perhaps you find some issues then.

Comment: Garh.. I had the init array placed wrong! I could not see the forest for the trees so I missed it completely!